# Adding Matrices with while loops

Tags: c

I need to add two 3x3 matrices together using while loops. I am able to read and print both matrices using while loops but cannot work out how to add the matrices with while loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int i=0,j=0,k=0,l=0,m=0,n=0;
    int a[3][3],b[3][3],c[3][3];

    printf("Enter the first matrix \n \n");
    while(i<3)
    {
        j=0;
        while(j<3)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("The first matrix is \n\n");
    i=0;
    while(i<3)
    {
        j=0;
        while(j<3)
        {
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 printf("Enter the second matrix \n \n");

    while(k<3)
    {
        l=0;
        while(l<3)
        {
            scanf("%d",&b[k][l]);
            l++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("The second matrix is \n\n");
    k=0;
    while(k<3)
    {
        l=0;
        while(l<3)
        {
            printf("%d ",b[k][l]);
            l++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        k++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    printf("The sum of the matrix's is \n \n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's the same style of double loop; just add each individual of `b[k][l]` and `a[k][l]` together and assign to `c[k][l]`.

Comment: Any reason you're not using for-loops? They'll essentially be the same, but semantically, it makes much more sense, since you loop over the dimensions (which are fixed in size).

Comment: From a glance at your code, I think your problem comes from a misconception that the array indices belong to a particular array. You use i and j only for a, and k and l only for b. You can just reset and recycle the same indices for different arrays.

Comment: Have you heard of functions?  You should be using more of them.  The matrix reading code should be in a function, called twice, with two different matrices as the space to receive the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break your problem down into smaller sub problems to help solve it. 
EXAMPLE:

1. How to loop through a 2-D array?
2. How to get values and assign them to a variable from looping through the array?
3. How to manipulate the values to are obtaining (In your case adding them to something else)
4. How to insert these values into the correct position in a new array.

Answer (score 2):

```
int matrix_a [3][3] = {{1,2,3},{3,4,5},{4,5,6}};
int matrix_b [3][3] = {{5,6,7},{6,7,8},{7,8,9}};

int i = 0;
while (i < 3) {
   j = 0;
   while (j < 3) {
      matrix_a[i][j] += matrix[i][j];
      ++ j;
   }
   ++ i;
}
```

`for` loops are a much better choice:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++ i) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++ j) {
      matrix_a[i][j] += matrix_b[i][j];
   }
}
```

---

Superoptimal pointer-arithmetic alternative:

```
int* ptr_a = matrix_a;
int* ptr_b = matrix_b;

int size = 3 * 3;
while (size --) {
   * ptr_a++ += * ptr_b++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below code to do the addition:

```
             k=0;
                while(k<3)
                {
                    l=0;
                    while(l<3)
                    {
                        c[k][l] = a[k][l]+b[k][l];
                        l++;
                    }
                    k++;
                }
```

And, to display your matrix, you can use for loop instead of while.

Example:

```
    for(int p =0;p<3;p++){
        for(int q=0;q<3;q++){
            c[p][q] = a[p][q] + b[p][q] ;
        }
    }

    for(int p =0;p<3;p++){
        for(int q=0;q<3;q++){
            printf("%d \t",c[p][q]) ;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```